# "An undefined behavior was detected: undefined is not an instance of java.lang.String"

Tags: scala.js

I am using scalajs/angulate

I have a problem that only occurs when using `type="email"` on a form. When i change it to `type="text"` the problem disappears.
The problem manifests itself:

- The email field does not change when typing
- Exception `"An undefined behavior was detected: undefined is not an instance of java.lang.String"`

This is my controller

```
class FooInfoController(…) extends Controller {
  var name: String = _
  var email: String = _
  …
}
```

And the html

```
 <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="FooInfoController as ctrl">
     <form ng-submit="ctrl.add()">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email</label>
             <input class="form-control" id="email" required maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email"
                    ng-model="ctrl.email"
                    placeholder="email address">
         </div>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is this really all the code you have? Is `FooInfoController` a Scala.js defined JS class? Where is the exception thrown?